# No log data in Elasticsearch with NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlog

I'm trying to log to Elasticsearch with NLog using NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch.
The index is created successfully but no log data found.

my NLog config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
    </extensions>
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="elastic" xsi:type="ElasticSearch" index="logs-elasticsearch-sample" documentType=""
                uri="http://localhost:9200" includeAllProperties="true"
                layout ="API:logs-elasticsearch-sample|${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" >
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="elastic" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'm using:
.net 6
NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch v7.7.0
NLog.Web.AspNetCore v4.14.0
Elasticsearch v7.17.1 (tried v8.1.0 too)

original tutorial:
https://dev.to/majidqafouri/writing-logs-into-elastic-with-nlog-elk-and-net-5-0-246c

I'm new to elasticsearch to be honest so I might did something wrong, but the steps are fairly simple.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.1/docker.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/docker.html

I'm using docker containers for elasticsearch and kibana in my tests.
also tried logging using console app (.net core 3.1) while creating the elastic target for Nlog programmatically and I got the same result.

I can create and query data from kibana just fine by the way.

Comment: Checked if [NLog.config has been deployed](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting) ? Tried to enable the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) at debug-level ?

Comment: NLog InternalLogger was a great help indeed, thank you

Answer (score 3):

so for anyone who have problem with NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch.
few points to consider:

1. DocumentType is deprecated in v7.x and deleted in v8.x so you have to set it to empty for v8.x
2. elasticsearch index should be lower case
3. if your index start with logs-*, make sure to create an index template for it with higher priority: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-create-indices/254204/3

Comment: Adding documentType="" to target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" solved the issue.


<target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" index="${elasticSearchIndex}" uri="${elasticSearchUri}" username="${elasticSearchUsername}" password="${elasticSearchPassword}" documentType="">

Answer (score 1):

add this config to NLog.config to get log for finding problem

```
<nlog 
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\work\log.txt">
```

if there were any problems on log to elastic can find on 'c:\work\log.txt'